# How can I make a 3x1 responsive footer with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="sc-content-footer container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="images/BSY_LOGO_SIGNAGE.png">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This just doesn't work, items appear on top of each other and dont react responsively. I just need to have:

```
mailchimp form --- logo --- mailchimp form
```

and then on smaller viewports,

```
 form
 form
 logo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 beta 2, then you do not have to add the number in the column, please try the below code:

```
<div class="sc-content-footer container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="images/BSY_LOGO_SIGNAGE.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm">
        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

alternatively you can also try below code which will take care of the all the screen sizes:

```
<div class="sc-content-footer container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
            </div>

            <div class="col">
            <img src="images/BSY_LOGO_SIGNAGE.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: use `text-center` class along with `col-sm` and try

Answer (score 0):

Have you included bootstrap-grid.css?
See this: https://jsfiddle.net/cons0vw7

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap-grid.css
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">col1</div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">c0l2</div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">col3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Working example https://www.codeply.com/go/pA3GBinWx4